# MS Access SQL Compare Consecutive Rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have a table name "T1' with a column name "Con". I need to find Unique and Repeat through additional columns as Unique and Repeat comparing consicutive rows. If row match with immediate row then repeat column will show "1" or else "0" and if row doesn't match with immediate row then Unique column will show "1" or else "0".

[image]

Comment: Screenshot is attached

Comment: . . You need a column that specifies the ordering of the table.

Comment: Yes, Data is already sorted

Comment: . . In general in relational databases, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless the table has a column with that ordering.

Comment: CON column will be always ordered asc

Comment: . . I get that, but there the ordering is not stable, because there are duplicates.  So, the table is not quite as ordered as you would like.  Do you have any other columns?

Comment: yes, i have more columns. but i need to compare like in excel a2 to a3 and so on. you can check the expected result from upper screenshot with shaded rows.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data, you don't need to look at the "next" row.  This logic does what you want:

```
select t1.con,
       iif(cnt = 1, 1, 0) as is_unique,
       iif(cnt > 1, 1, 0) as is_repeat
from t1 inner join
     (select t1.con, count(*) as cnt
      from t1
      group by t1.con
     ) as tt1
     on t1.con = tt1.con;
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your answer but Here counted duplicate value not repeat. I need compare 1st row to 2nd row, 2nd row to 3rd row and so on. So that when "030120191303377845AT Acquisition Installment Q" 6th row compare with 7th row it will show repeat but when same "030120191303377845AT Acquisition Installment Q" 7th row compare with 8th Row "030120191304083589AT Balance Transfr Query Q" it will not be Repeat and will return "0".